# Why is function appending the wrong value to list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am creating a program that takes a dictionary with departments and who is in it, for example this dictionary here:

```
{"local": ["admin", "userA"],
 "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
 "administrator": ["admin"] }
```

And then returns a dictionary with all users as keys and a list of departments they are in as the value.

For example, the output for the previously given list is supposed to be:

```
{"admin" : ["local", "public", "administrator"],
 "userA" : ["local"],
 "userB" : ["public"]}
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    # Go through group_dictionary
    
    user_groups["admin"] = []
    user_groups["userA"] = []
    user_groups["userB"] = []

    for x in group_dictionary.values():
        # Now go through the users in the group
        for user in x:
            if user in group_dictionary["local"]:
                user_groups[user].append("local")
            elif user in group_dictionary["public"]:
                user_groups[user].append("public")
            elif user in group_dictionary["administrator"]:
                user_groups[user].append("administrator")


            # Now add the group to the the list of
# groups for this user, creating the entry
# in the dictionary if necessary

    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
        "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
        "administrator": ["admin"] }))
```

However, I am getting this output:

```
{'admin': ['local', 'local', 'local'],
 'userA': ['local'],
 'userB': ['public']}
```

In addition, I am defining the users in my function on lines 5-7 of my code. What am I supposed to do to make sure my code works for any given department and any given user?

For example, a user called `"owner"` and a department called `"groupWorkspace"` wouldn't work because I didn't define them in my code. Can someone explain how to fix this?

Comment: `admin` is always in `local` so elif for `public` and `administrator` will never run

Comment: @Epsi95 how can i prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't expect this to be the "Best" or most performant solution. I do however hope that the logic is clear and easy to follow.

*Please note: I am using terrible variable names on purpose. Hopefully nudging "anyone" to use it as an example or to understand the logic, and implement it ones self in your project. **Making it less likely you will simply Copy+Paste without fully understanding or even editing this example** *

The result of the following code is:

```
{ 'admin': ['local', 'public', 'administrator'], 
  'userA': ['local'], 
  'userB': ['public'] }
```

And finally the code to do the restructure, and potentially remove duplicates, in case your input data is not unique.

```
input = {
"local": ["admin", "userA"],
"public":  ["admin", "userB"],
"administrator": ["admin"]
}

def group_flip(input):
    # container for the result { user: [groups...], ...} structured result
    # this will be built up while iterating over the input
    user_groups = {}

    for g, us in input.items():
        # for each user in group
        for u in us:
            # we need to add it to the user_groups
            if not u in user_groups.keys():
                user_groups[u] = [g]
                continue
        
            # if not in list, add it
            if not g in user_groups[u]:
                user_groups[u].append(g)

    print(user_groups)
    return user_groups



if __name__ == '__main__':
    group_flip(input)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) we can do this quite easily:

```
groups = {"local": ["admin", "userA"],
          "public": ["admin", "userB"],
          "administrator": ["admin"]}

user_groups = {}
for group, users in groups.items():
    for user in users:
        user_groups.setdefault(user, []).append(group)

print(user_groups)
```

Output:

```
{'admin': ['local', 'public', 'administrator'],
 'userA': ['local'],
 'userB': ['public']}
```

Comment: Nice one - for meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 1):

A very bad approach, but I hope you will understand where you were wrong. admin is always in local so `elif` for public and administrator will never run

```py
def groups_per_user(group_dictionary):
    user_groups = {}
    # Go through group_dictionary
    
    user_groups["admin"] = []
    user_groups["userA"] = []
    user_groups["userB"] = []

    for x in group_dictionary.values():
        # Now go through the users in the group
        for user in x:
            if user in group_dictionary["local"]:
                user_groups[user].append("local")
            if user in group_dictionary["public"]:
                user_groups[user].append("public")
            if user in group_dictionary["administrator"]:
                user_groups[user].append("administrator")
            
    for k,v in user_groups.items():
        user_groups[k] = list(set(v))


            # Now add the group to the the list of
# groups for this user, creating the entry
# in the dictionary if necessary

    return(user_groups)

print(groups_per_user({"local": ["admin", "userA"],
        "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
        "administrator": ["admin"] }))

#{'admin': ['administrator', 'local', 'public'], 'userA': ['local'], 'userB': ['public']}
```

Oneliner just for fun

```py
d = {"local": ["admin", "userA"],
        "public":  ["admin", "userB"],
        "administrator": ["admin"] }

dict((k,[i[-1] for i in g]) for k, g in groupby(sorted(each_pair for k,v in d.items() for each_pair in sorted(map(lambda x: x[::-1], product([k],v)))), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```